# React Native making app interactive together with RN navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am making the app reactive by passing up argument from  feature to main App.js like this.
But how do I do that if I am using react navigation native?

Here is Focus feature, I want it to pass 'addSubject' from 'Home' screen:

```js
export const Focus = ({addSubject}) => {  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            title: 'My home',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
          }}
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
```

Here is Home screen, I need to go with 'navigation' but

```js
{addSubject}
```

Should be there too somewhere

```js
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState(null);
  console.log(subject);  
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue,
      }}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Home Screen</Text>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          label="What would you like to do ?"
          onChangeText={setSubject}
        />
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <RoundedButton
            title="+"
            size={50}
            onPress={() => addSubject(subject)}
          />
        </View>
```

Here is main App.js which I want to pass value to:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [currentSubject, setCurrentSubject] = useState(null);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {!currentSubject ? (
        <Focus addSubject={setCurrentSubject} />
      ) : (
        <View>
          <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>I am going to render the timer</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Different zones to place the {addSubject} to move information up to the App.js.

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: To render text entered in the field by button.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@jurajbe/gg here is the snack
In the tutorial there is passing from <focus /> feature's input to the App.js but I have navigation there, thats what I suppose is exported and therefor not the main screen which should be exporting, but I just guess. Is there a solution?

Comment: you need to pass params to homescreen am I right ?

Comment: yes, I want to pass data from 'HomeScreen' to the App.js (main file) but over the navigation.stack (or if possible somehow else)

Comment: you are in wrong path  you need to use redux for this